# Class style in Ionic 2 not working

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 app and have the following two files in pages/home folder:

home.html:

```
<ion-list-header class="list">Your List</ion-list-header>
```

home.scss:

```
.list {
    color: green;
}
```

Any ideas why is this not working? The file is properly referenced and the rest of the styles are working properly, but whenever I use class attribute, it is not picking up the styles(tried putting class on other elements as well).

Comment: If you inspect the elements in your browser, is the class `list` actually applied?

Comment: did you try the color attribute as in `color="green"`

Comment: No, the class is not applied. The question is not "Why is it not applied?", because I didn't know the class is not applied .

Comment: When I manually add the class, it works, but I don't get why the class is not applied?

Comment: "color: green" works with other selectors, so it should not be the problem

Comment: @Mario Are you sure your code isn't overwritten by a default color in the css?

Comment: The class is not there when I start the app. When I manually add the class, the css style kicks in. So the real problem must be the class not being applied? Any ideas why?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to reproduce the issue, have a look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnlzMKAyo9djEjY25lKi?p=preview) and feel free to share one with minimal code that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it with every html element and it didn't work. Made the change in the .ts file for the live reload and it still didn't apply.

Then refreshed the page also and it kicked in.

I will advise refreshing everything when it comes to `html/css` and on **ticking** "**Disable cache**" in developer tools in Google chrome as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine.I have tested it.It seems your problem is with the live reloader issue.That is why it didn't apply.

**Solution:** Just change the `semi colon(i.e. ;)` on your `home.ts` file and let it reload the server.All things should be fine then :)